# function declarations should not be placed in blocks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

My JavaScript (below) is very **untidy** and contains an **error** which I have been unable to resolve. The error is within the showPosition function (*I have a function within a function, which isn't recommended*).
I have just started experimenting with JavaScript, so I apologise if this is a simple question. I have also provided a jsFiddle of my JavaScript which highlights the area I'm stuck with (http://jsfiddle.net/dnUTx/).

In jsFiddle, I get an error on line 25 - 'function declarations should not be placed in blocks'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// JavaScript Document

var x = document.getElementById("info");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError, clearWatch, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 30000,
            timeout: 30000
        });
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Your browser does not support the geolocation () API.";
    }
}
var flightPathCoordinates = [];
var lat1, lng1, first_check = false;

function showPosition(position) {
    if (!first_check) {
        lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
        lng1 = position.coords.longitude;
        first_check = true;
    } else {
        function distanceFrom(points) {
            var lat1 = points.lat1;
            var radianLat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);
            var lng1 = points.lng1;
            var radianLng1 = lng1 * (Math.PI / 180);
            var lat2 = points.lat2;
            var radianLat2 = lat2 * (Math.PI / 180);
            var lng2 = points.lng2;
            var radianLng2 = lng2 * (Math.PI / 180);
            var earth_radius = 3959; // or 6371 for kilometers
            var diffLat = (radianLat1 - radianLat2);
            var diffLng = (radianLng1 - radianLng2);
            var sinLat = Math.sin(diffLat / 2);
            var sinLng = Math.sin(diffLng / 2);
            var a = Math.pow(sinLat, 2.0) + Math.cos(radianLat1) * Math.cos(radianLat2) * Math.pow(sinLng, 2.0);
            var distance = earth_radius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt(a)));
            return distance.toFixed(3);
        }
        var distance = distanceFrom({
            "lat1": lat1,
            "lng1": lng1,
            "lat2": position.coords.latitude,
            "lng2": position.coords.longitude
        });
    }
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
        "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
        "<br>Altitude: " + position.coords.altitude +
        "<br>Altitude Accuracy: " + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy +
        "<br>Heading: " + position.coords.heading +
        "<br>Speed (km): " + position.coords.speed * 3.6 +
        "<br>Timestamp: " + new Date(position.timestamp).toLocaleString() +
        "<br>Distance Travelled (km): " + distance +
        "<br>Stopwatch: " + min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec;

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder');

    var myOptions = {
        center: latlon,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);

    //Bicycle Store
    var request = {
        location: (latlon),
        radius: '1000',
        types: ['bicycle_store']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

        //Custom Marker 1
        var image1 = '../images/logo_marker1.png';
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map: map,
            icon: image1,
            title: "Bicycle Store"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    //Bicycle Layer
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(map);

    //Custom Marker 2
    var image2 = '../images/logo_marker2.png';
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlon,
        map: map,
        icon: image2,
        title: "You are here!"
    });

    //Panoramio Layer
    var panoramioLayer = new google.maps.panoramio.PanoramioLayer();

    panoramioLayer.setUserId("7467601");
    panoramioLayer.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(panoramioLayer, 'click', function (event) {
        var attribution = document.createTextNode(event.featureDetails.title + ": " + event.featureDetails.author);
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", event.featureDetails.url);
        link.appendChild(attribution);
    });

    //Polyline Layer
    flightPathCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPathCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function showError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation.";
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable.";
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out.";
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred.";
            break;
    }
}

function clearWatch() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(showPosition);
}
```

Comment: You're not even going to tell us what the problem is?  You want us to try to guess what the problem is?

Comment: As stated above, the problem is with the showPosition function. I have a function (distanceFrom) within the showPosition function which JavaScript doesn't like. So I am confused as to where else I could put it within the document

Comment: I don't know from what language you got that "isn't recommended" advise from but FWIW in javascript creating a function inside another function is normal and is NOT "not recommended". Just like any other language feature it's a tool and you use it when you need it. If you look at most modern javascript code you'll see it quite a lot.

Comment: What specifically is the problem with the `showPosition()` function?  Does it cause a javascript error?  If so, what error on what line?  Does it give you the wrong result?  If you want help, you have to give us a good description of what exact problem you need solved.  FYI, there's nothing wrong with a function in a function - that's a well-used technique in javascript.

Comment: I would not use the syntactic sugar 'function' with nested functions. To avoid ambiguity about the scope in such cases I advise to do `var distanceFrom=function(points){  //statements };`  OR `window.distanceFrom=function(points){ //statements };` if you'd want the function to be globally available.

Comment: @jfriend00 In jsFiddle, I get an error on line 25 - 'function declarations should not be placed in blocks'.

Comment: I don't get that error in Chrome.  But, a more proper place to declare a nested function is at the top of a function block, not in the middle like you have it.  Internally, it is hoisted to the top anyway.

Comment: jshint is not my favorite, they never should have replaced the proper jslint.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your time and effort. So I should cut and paste the function distanceFrom at the top of the page?

Comment: Move it to the top of the function it is nested in.  If this is just a jslint recommendation, you can also ignore it as it's not causing any actual problems, but putting a nested function inside a block can be confusing to those reading the function (which is why it's recommended to put them at the top of the host function declaration).

Comment: @slebetman: JSHint and JSLint are right actually. Although there is nothing wrong with nested functions generally, you can not use a `function declaration` inside a block `{}` (from say a if/else/for/while..). I updated my answer explaining that in further detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to me the question is perfectly clear and even provides a jsfiddle, +1 for new member.

Your problem is 2-fold:

You use local variable `distance` to build your `x.innerHTML` string.
However, `distance` is only defined (assigned to be precise) in the `else` clause of your if-statement.

Secondly, you use a 'function declaration' inside a block `{}`, which is syntactically illegal! This is because Blocks can only contain Statements, not SourceElements, which FunctionDeclaration is.
So, inside an if/else/while/for block you must use a 'function expression';
eg: `var identifier=function(//args){//code};`
*This is the reason for your error-message that JSHint in JSFiddle gives.*

See [this fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/dnUTx/1/) to see my changes (just making jshint validate, but since this is just part of some code there is no way for me to try it out further).

I added `var distance=0` as a local variable before your first `if`-clause in your function `showPosition` and changed the `function declaration` to a `function expression` inside your `else`-clause.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort! That's sorted the minor problem I was having. Now the next part is to store the distance value into local Storage which I'm sure I'll struggle with. lol

Comment: updated my answer to explain a more serious problem I missed yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for your time GitaarLAB. So the code you updated yesterday in jsFiddle is illegal? If so, how could I resolve this problem?

Comment: The edits I made (in the jsfiddle) are legal (making jshint validate). It is just that the original answer could be interpreted as if the change from `function distanceFrom(){ ` to `var distanceFrom=function(){ ` was a style-thing, whilst it actually is a rules-thing. More importantly, it bridges the gap between your statement (based on the JSHint's error-message) that you '*have a function within a function, which isn't recommended*' and the comments (including mine) that tell you there is nothing wrong with nested functions. It's how you define them. See also http://kangax.github.com/nfe/